# How to unlist the lm fit in order to make a boxplot?

Tags: r, regression, boxplot

I need to visualize data using boxplot, but it can not generate a list object. I tried simply using `unlist` on the lm-object, but it still says that the data is a list. I have read about this in R documentation, that the unlisting lm fit is a list which has individual residuals as components. How can I do it?

```
new_data.ref_conc <- lm(formula = conc~OD, data=new_data)
unlist(new_data.ref_conc)
boxplot(new_data.ref_conc~control+treat, data=new_data)
```

Comment: Calling `unlist` on a `lm` object does not make much sense. If you need to extract an element from that object, try `str(new_data.ref_conc)` you'll see what it contains.

For the visualization, check out the `visreg` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/index.html

Comment: what do you want to make a boxplot of? The fitted values of the regression or the residuals?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way how to boxplot the residuals (epsilon) and  the fitted values (yhat) of linear regression. Since you did not provide your data, I created my own:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rexp(100, 1)
y <- 1 + 2*x + rnorm(100) 
lm_obj <- lm(y~x)

plotdata <- data.frame(type = rep(c("res", "yhat"), each = 100),
                       value = c(residuals(lm_obj), fitted(lm_obj)))

boxplot(value~type, data = plotdata, col = c("dodgerblue", "hotpink2"), pch = 16,
        names = c("Residuals", "Fitted Values"), main = "My Boxplot")
```

[image]

Comment: R has extractor functions: `residuals()` and `fitted()`. Users are encouraged to use these instead of extracting internal components of a model object.